# Getting error on Masonry's container.append Uncaught TypeError: Object has no method filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am implementing infinite scroll on my web page which displays images. Images are aligned using [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/). Initially when the page loads I only put 10 images in `#container` div. And all images get aligned properly using below code with no errors in chrome script console.

```
var $container = $('#container');
        $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
        $('#container').masonry({
          itemSelector: '.box',
          columnWidth: 200,
          isAnimated: true
        });
    });
```

but as user scrolls down I do

```
$.ajax({
         url: "load.php?offset="+1+"&quantity="+1,
         success: function(html){
         if(html){
                  var $container = $('#container');
                  var $test = "<div>even doing this causes error </div>";
              $container.append($test).masonry('appended',$test);
        }
  });
```

Now when ever I scroll down I get below error in chrome console and appended images come up stacked.

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Object <div class....... </div>  has no method filter
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't fit to your error message. The error message you get with this code is `Uncaught TypeError: Object $test has no method 'filter'`. If you remove the quotes around `$test`, you get `Uncaught TypeError: Object <div>even doing this causes error </div> has no method 'filter'`. Obviously, you should pass a jQuery object to `masonry()` instead of a String.

Comment: when you say `pass a jquery object` what do you mean? $test is a variable

Comment: Which contains a String ("<div>even doing this causes error </div>"). I have never used masonry but from the error message I guess it tries to call `$test.filter(...)`, which is a method of a jQuery object and doesn't work on a String object. In your example, replace the line above with `var $test = $("<div>even doing this causes error </div>");`. That makes a jQuery object from the string. The error should go away.

Comment: ok, Let me try to create a div element by `document.createElement` and see how that goes

Comment: No, you need a jQuery element, not just a JavaScript element. You can create one by `document.createElement` but then you have to convert it to a jQuery element again.

Comment: @j0ker you were right, please post your comment as answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As I stated in my comment, the error message you get is typical when working with jQuery. `filter()` is a method of jQuery objects. masonry seems to try to call it on whatever object is inside your `$test` variable, which, in your example, is a String object. Basically, it calls

```
"<div>even doing this causes error </div>".filter(...)
```

which produces your error.

To make things work, you have to pass the `masonry()` method a jQuery object instead of a String (or any other JavaScript object). If you have a String, e.g. as a result of an AJAX call, you can convert that to a jQuery object by using the jQuery function on it. For your example:

```
$test = $("<div>even doing this causes error </div>");
```

This creates a jQuery div-object which should be usable with masonry.

Another hint: You seem to prefix all your JavaScript variables with a `$` sign. While this is up to you, I would recommend to prefix only variables that hold jQuery objects with `$` and don't prefix any other variables. So, for Strings you would just use `var test = "String";`. That's a convention I found quite useful. Also, it will make it easier for other people to understand your code.

Comment: This also works if you have html coming from an AJAX call:
var boxes = $(ajaxContent.html());
$('#container').append(boxes).masonry('appended', boxes);